# How to create a custom pipe that paginates data in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to write a custom pipe in Angular that takes two parameters: an array of objects and a page number. The pipe would filter out the data so that each page displays 100 records of the data. As an example, page 1 displays records 0-99, page 2 displays records 100-199, page 3 displays records 200-299 etc.

The data.json contains an array that has 1300 objects. Here a piece of the data: https://pastebin.com/7V2DNj8W

Each object in the data are like the one following:

```
{
    "location_type": "KAUPPAKESKUS",
    "postalcode": "2770",
    "availability": "24 H AUKIOLO",
    "location": "ESPOONTORI /INSTRUMENTARIUM",
    "municipality": "ESPOO",
    "target_address": "KAMREERINTIE 3",
    "availability_details": "",
    "coordinates_lon": "24.656450",
    "coordinates_lat": "60.203750"
}
```

The following **pagination.pipe.ts** takes in `atms[]` and `page` as parameters, makes sure that the indexes of objects in `atms[]` correlate to the `page` and returns the data.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

interface atm {
    target_address: string,
    postalcode: string,
    municipality: string,
    location: string,
    location_type: string,
    availability: string,
    availability_details: string,
    coordinates_lat: string,
    coordinates_lon: string
}

@Pipe({
  name: 'pagination'
})
export class PaginationPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(atms: atm[], page: number): any {

    let data: atm[] = [];
    let index= 0;
    let per_page = 100;

    for (let atm of atms) {
      if (index >= (page * per_page) && index < (page + 1) * per_page) {
        console.log(index);
        data.push(atm);
        index++;
      }
    }

    return data;

  }

}
```

If I browse to a URL `http://localhost:4200/page/0` the first 100 records (0-99) are successfully printed out and the console output is as expected: numbers 0-99. However, on the URL address `http://localhost:4200/page/1` nothing is being printed out to the console nor to a table in page.component.html. I was expecting to see numbers 100-199 being printed out to the console on `/page/1` and the data being printed out a table.

EDIT:

Here is **page.component.html**:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Availability</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let atm of atms | pagination:page">
        <td>{{ atm.target_address }}, {{ atm.postalcode }}
          {{ atm.municipality }}</td>
        <td>{{ atm.location }}, {{ atm.location_type }}</td>
        <td>{{ atm.availability }} {{ atm.availability_details }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

and here is **page.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ATMsService } from './atms.service';

interface atm {
    target_address: string,
    postalcode: string,
    municipality: string,
    location: string,
    location_type: string,
    availability: string,
    availability_details: string,
    coordinates_lat: string,
    coordinates_lon: string
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-page',
  templateUrl: './page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page.component.css']
})
export class PageComponent implements OnInit {

  page: number;  
  atms: atm[] = [];

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private service: ATMsService
    ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getAll().then((data) => {
      this.atms = data;
    })

    this.route.params.subscribe(parameters => {
      this.page = parameters.page;
    })
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you please add the code where you are watching the page and sending that value into the pipe?

Comment: @OneLunch Man I provided the code for you there.

Comment: If you log just inside of your `transform` method, does it trigger?

Comment: What should I log there? `atms`? If so, then yes, that does log successfully.

Comment: Anything to see if it's even triggering.

Comment: Here is a screenshot from the console on `/page/1`: https://i.imgur.com/x8bbIlG.png As you can see, the data appears to be logging correctly, but nothing is being printed out to the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with the "index" logic.

```
let index = 0;

...

if (index >= (page * per_page) && index < (page + 1) * per_page) {
```

If index is always zero, then-
page 0:

```
if (0 >= (0 * 100) && 0 < (0 + 1) * 100) // true, will build list
```

page 1:

```
if (0 >= (1 * 100) && 0 < (1 + 1) * 100) // false, (0 >= (1 * 100) will never be true
```

pages > 1:

```
// similar answer as 1
```

You may want to set your index to start at page * page_size - 1

Comment: I moved `index++` to outside of the if statement, and now `/page/1` displays records ranging from 100-1099 even though I'm still expecting to see records ranging from 100 to 199. What's the issue?

Comment: Instead of auto incrementing and such, I'd suggest something like myArray.slice with a check on maxLength. 
Something like `atms.slice(startIndex, endIndex)` you'll have to compute if it should end at endIndex or just pass the startIndex (which will fetch all remaining).

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the variable `page` has a type of `string` instead of `number`. Without having a type of `number`, the following expression when `page`is 1 is calculated wrong:

`let lastIndex = page + 1 // prints out 11 instead of 2`

I fixed this by typing the variable `page` to `number`:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(parameters => {
        this.page = +parameters.page;
    })
}
```

The statement `index++` needs to moved outside of the `if` statement so that the `index` is always increased in every `for` loop:

```
for (let atm of atms) {
  if (index >= (page * per_page) && index < (page + 1) * per_page) {
    data.push(atm);
  }
  index++;
}
```